# Business card recognition. How can I extract data from a business card using Google ML Kit in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dart-pub, google-mlkit

I'm working on a business card project in Flutter. My goal is to digitally extract data from a photo or an image from the gallery on a mobile phone, including fields like:
{name, surname, address, title1, title2, city, country, company number, fax, mobile number, etc.}
I've had trouble handling the data using regex and .contains since there are various card designs, and the data is not consistently located in the same place. I'm using ML Kit's line-by-line text recognition to capture the data and store it in a list. Then, I've created a CardVisitModel to attempt to parse the collected data into properties based on their characteristics.

Now, the challenge is how to control this data parsing process. As I mentioned earlier, there are many different types of business cards, and the fields can be located anywhere on the card.

I tried regex / '.contains' function and flutter google ml data extraction kit. The ml kit only can handle address phone email so if i use it. I still couldn't mapping name,surname,city, etc.
Do u have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `google_ml_kit` to extract the data in string from the image and further you can use the Google Gemini Api to recognize the data like email, company name, phone number.

Here below is the sample of code:

```
Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      readTextFromImage(image: File(pickedFile.path));
    }
}

Future<void> readTextFromImage({required File image}) async {
    final inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(image);
    final textRecognizer = TextRecognizer(script: TextRecognitionScript.latin);
    final RecognizedText recognizedText =
        await textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);
    String text = recognizedText.text;
    var info = text.replaceAll('\n', ' ');

    log(info);
    callGemini(str: info);

    textRecognizer.close();
    setState(() {
      extractedData = text;
    });
}

callGemini({required String str}) {
    EasyLoading.show();
    gemini
        .generateFromText(
            "${str} Extract comany_name,person name,email,website,phone_number(only one),address(In single string) in json object")
        .then((value) {
      EasyLoading.showSuccess("Data Extracted Successfully");
      log("Data fetched");
      var filterData = value.text.replaceAll('`', "");
      log(filterData);
      var mapData = json.decode(filterData);
      log(mapData["company_name"]);
      log(mapData["person_name"]);
      log(mapData["email"]);
      log(mapData["website"]);
      log(mapData["phone_number"]);
      log(mapData["address"]);
    });
}
```